# Namespaces (Default) in JDOM

Tags: java, xml, jdom

I am trying to produce a XML document using the newest JDOM package. I'm having trouble with the root element and the namespaces. I need to produce this root element:

```
<ManageBuildingsRequest 
    xmlns="http://www.energystar.gov/manageBldgs/req" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.energystar.gov/manageBldgs/req 
                        http://estar8.energystar.gov/ESES/ABS20/Schemas/ManageBuildingsRequest.xsd">
```

I use this code:

```
Element root = new Element("ManageBuildingsRequest");
root.setNamespace(Namespace.getNamespace("http://www.energystar.gov/manageBldgs/req"));
Namespace XSI = Namespace.getNamespace("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
root.addNamespaceDeclaration(XSI);
root.setAttribute("schemaLocation", "http://www.energystar.gov/manageBldgs/req http://estar8.energystar.gov/ESES/ABS20/Schemas/ManageBuildingsRequest.xsd", XSI);

Element customer = new Element("customer");
root.addContent(customer);
doc.addContent(root); // doc jdom Document
```

However, the next element after ManageBuildingsRequest has the default namespace as well, which breaks the validation:

```
<customer xmlns="">
```

Any help? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you post the code generating your xml please?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [constructor](http://jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom/Element.html#Element%28java.lang.String%29) you're using for the `customer` element creates it with no namespace. You should use the constructor with the `Namespace` as parameter. You can also reuse the same `Namespace` object for both root and customer elements.

```
Namespace namespace = Namespace.getNamespace("http://www.energystar.gov/manageBldgs/req");
Element root = new Element("ManageBuildingsRequest", namespace);
Namespace XSI = Namespace.getNamespace("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
root.addNamespaceDeclaration(XSI);
root.setAttribute("schemaLocation", "http://www.energystar.gov/manageBldgs/req http://estar8.energystar.gov/ESES/ABS20/Schemas/ManageBuildingsRequest.xsd", XSI);

Element customer = new Element("customer", namespace);
root.addContent(customer);
doc.addContent(root); // doc jdom Document
```

Comment: You're right, but I am not quite sure why. I have to pass the namespace to every child which I had a lot of - became quite a pain, but this fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: @jsn Ran into the same issue and completely agree with you. This is a terrible API. Was hoping to find a better solution.

Comment: A detailed explanation is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26674924/prevent-jdom2-from-creating-xmlns

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternate approach that implements a custom XMLOutputProcessor that skips emitting empty namespace declarations:

```
public class CustomXMLOutputProcessor extends AbstractXMLOutputProcessor {
    protected void printNamespace(Writer out, FormatStack fstack, Namespace ns)
            throws java.io.IOException {
        System.out.println("namespace is " + ns);
        if (ns == Namespace.NO_NAMESPACE) {
            System.out.println("refusing to print empty namespace");
            return;
        } else {
            super.printNamespace(out, fstack, ns);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The post may be old but this was a rather elegant workaround to a troubled API.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tried javanna's code but unfortunately it kept on generating the empty namespaces in the document's contents. After trying bearontheroof's code the XML exported just fine.

You would have to do something like this after creating the custom class:

```
CustomXMLOutputProcessor output = new CustomXMLOutputProcessor();
output.process(new FileWriter("/path/to/folder/generatedXML.xml"), Format.getPrettyFormat(), document);
```