# Prevent JDOM2 from creating xmlns=""

Tags: java, jdom, jdom-2

I try to add new `<class>` elements to a persistence.xml file with JDOM2.

```
persistenceUnitEl.add(new Element("class").addContent(className));
```

The problem is that jdom2 always adds `xmlns=""` to the `<class>` elements.

How can i prevent this?

`removeAttribute("xmlns")` does not work and `removeNameSpace(el.getNameSpace())` also does not work.

Answer (score 4):

JDOM only adds the `xmlns=""` if you add child elements to other elements that are already in a namespace. The default Namespace in XML is the one which has no prefix. In the following example:

```
<root>
    <child />
</root>
```

There are no namespace prefixes, and the default namespace is "".

The above XML snippet is semantically identical to:

```
<root xmlns="" >
    <child />
</root>
```

The `xmlns=""` means that, any time you see an element that has no prefix, that you should put it in the 'empty' namespace "".

Now, if you want to put things in a namespace, and have a prefix, you would do:

```
<ns:root xmlns:ns="http://mynamespace">
    <ns:child />
</ns:root>
```

Note that the root and child elements in the above example are in the namespace `http://mynamespace`, and that namespace has the prefix `ns`. The above code would be semantically identical to (has the same meaning as):

```
<root xmlns="http://mynamespace">
    <child />
</root>
```

In the above example, the default namespace is changed from "" to be `http://mynamespace`, so now elements that have no prefix are in that default namespace `http://mynamespace`. To reiterate, the following two documents are identical:

```
<ns:root xmlns:ns="http://mynamespace">
    <ns:child />
</ns:root>
```

and

```
<root xmlns="http://mynamespace">
    <child />
</root>
```

Now, what does all of this have to do with your problem?

Well, your element `persistenceUnitEl` must be in a default namespace that is not "". Somewhere on that element, or on of it's parents, you have something like:

```
<tagname xmlns="...something....">
    <PersistenceUnit>
    </PersistenceUnit>
</tagname>
```

In the above, the `PersistenceUnit` is in the namespace `...something....`. Now, you are asking JDOM to add the element `new Element("class")` to the document, so you are getting:

```
<tagname xmlns="...something....">
    <PersistenceUnit>
        <class xmlns="" />
    </PersistenceUnit>
</tagname>
```

The reason is because you are telling JDOM to put it in the "" namespace (Namespace.NO_NAMESPACE). See the documentation for JDOM here: [`new Element(String name)`](http://jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/Element.html#Element(java.lang.String)).

instead, what you want to do, is put it in the same namespace as the parent:

```
Namespace parentNamespace = persistenceUnitEl.getNamespace();
persistenceUnitEl.add(new Element("class", parentNamespace).addContent(className));
```

Now, the real question is whether the "class" element actually belongs in the same namespace as the parent, or not. But that is a question only you can answer.

**Resources**:

- [Namespace specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/)
- [Decent introduction](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/1999/01/namespaces.html)
- [A tutorial (quite advanced)](http://www.xmlmaster.org/en/article/d01/c10/)
- [JDOM's NamespaceAware](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/NamespaceAware.html) documentation
- [JDOM's FAQ](http://www.jdom.org/docs/faq.html#a0260)

Comment: Thank you !! your explanation helped me to understand how Name Spaces work.

Comment: This answer should be accepted as the right answer (even after 3 years).

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, I think this is what you want.

```
<RootTagname xmlns="...some namespace....">
    <SubTag>
        <NewElement yourAttrib="1"/>
    </SubTag> 
</RootTagname >
```

This is what you get.

```
<RootTagname xmlns="...some namespace....">
    <SubTag>
        <NewElement xmlns="" yourAttrib="1"/>
    </SubTag> 
</RootTagname >
```

Use the below snippet to create the new Element

```
Element newElement = new Element("NewElement", subElement.getNamespace());
```

Here is the full code.

```
Namespace namespace = Namespace.getNamespace("prefix", ".....some namespace....");
XPathBuilder<Element> subTagXpathelementBuilder = new XPathBuilder<Element>("//prefix:SubTag", Filters.element());
subTagXpathelementBuilder.setNamespace(namespace);
XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.instance();

Document doc = (Document) builder.build(xmlFile);

XPathExpression<Element> xpath = subTagXpathelementBuilder .compileWith(xpathFactory);
List<Element> subElementsList = xpath.evaluate(doc);
for (Element subElement : subElementsList ) {
    Element newElement = new Element("NewElement", subElement.getNamespace());

    List<Attribute> newElementAttribList = newElement.getAttributes();
    newElementAttribList .add(new Attribute("yourAttrib", "1"));
    subElement .addContent(newElement);
}
```